# Weird login issue with Sharepoint 2010 site

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, sharepoint-2010

I am facing a weird authentication issue for an intranet sharepoint 2010 site.

When a user from site owner group tries to access the site by this URL, 
**http://machine name:1111/** a windows credential pops up, even if user provides correct login details, he is not able to log in. But when user tries to access this URL, **http://machine name:1111/SitePages/Home.aspx** he is able to login successfully.

The site uses classic authentication mode.

Please let me know, what could be the reason for such strange behaviour.

Regards
Naimish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it resolved now.

The physical directory should have 'Read' rights for Everyone. In my case, the folder 1111 has this rights removed. I have given the said rights and its working fine now.

Regards